# C# Question on a changing a string in a function

Tags: c#, string

Is it possible to change a string from another value? Here is my C# code:

```
if (QuestionNum == 1 && inputAnswer == RightAnswer || inputAnswer == RightAnswerLower)
{
    Program.GotQ1Correct = true;
}
```

I know that in Lua I could of just changed the `Program.GotQ1Correct = true;` part to

```
Program.GotQ[QuestionNum]Correct = true;
```

However was just wondering if this was possible in C#.

*Edit*

I'm very sorry if I wasn't clear before, so basically in the above lua code it would change GotQ1Correct to GotQ2Correct and so on and was just wondering if there was a similar, simple way to do this in C# without arrays.

Comment: Hi Max. Welcome to StackOverflow. It's really difficult to understand what you are asking because you have posted a tiny part of the code that leaves out most of the context. Can you create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Alright, what are you actually asking for? `Program.GotQ[QuestionNum] looks to be an array. Are you asking about arrays? Can't you create an `Question[] questions = { new Question("What is 2+2", "4"); };` or something?

Comment: yes its possible of course but your question is not at all clear. You seem, to be asking 'can I use an array of questions' answer 'yes you can'

Comment: You can modify the value of a string, but since a string is immutable the original reference still exists in memory until the garbage collector picks up that memory block.  Every instance or modification of a string is creating a new block of memory with your value.

Comment: @Greg - i think the 'string' part of the question is irrelevant. THe sample code is not doing anything to strings

Comment: You may also want to lookup a dictionary collection, it will reference a key value pair, in essence id which may be ideal for your question number and a proper answer in the value, so you can see if the user input matches.

Comment: @pm100 You may be correct, not sure what he meant by change a string in a function, so I assumed the value was being modified.  Not clear, so I figured I would add that feedback.

Answer (score 1):

seems like you need

```
    // assuming 10 questions
    var results = new bool[10];
    var correctAnswers = new string[10]; 
    var studAnswers = new string[10];

    for (int i; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        if(studAnswer[i].ToLower() == correctAnswers[i].ToLower())
            results[i] = true;

}
```

or slightly cleaner

```
 results[i] = studAnswer[i].ToLower() == correctAnswers[i].ToLower();
```

Comment: Simplest approach, just not sure the OP knows what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

For more clarity I might do a dictionary.

```
public IDictionary<int, bool> CheckAnswers(Dictionary<int, string> exam, Dictionary<int, string> answers)
{
     var results = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
     for(var index = 0; index < exam.Length; index++)
     {
         if(String.Compare(exam[index], answers[index], true) == 0)
             results.Add(exam[index], true);

          results.Add(exam[index], false);
     }

     return results;
}

var correct = CheckAnswers(..., ...).Where(answer => answer.Value == true).Count();
```

This solution needs refinement, but it is a nice compliment to PM's answer.  One of these should at least point you in the proper direction.

The reason I recommended a dictionary, would be you could pass an answer key and exam result.  Allowing you to see which are correct and wrong, then use a tally to get the score relatively easy.

Answer (score -1):

So if understand you want to access a property of an object by replacing the name of access property? 
You might want to check this post 
[accessing-object-property-as-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905187/accessing-object-property-as-string-and-setting-its-value)

Copied from the post

`System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop` `=typeof(YourType).GetProperty("PropertyName");`

`object value = prop.GetValue(yourInstance);
...
prop.SetValue(yourInstance, "value");`